# Modify Range in Line Chart with GoogleScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, linechart, addrange

I want to be able to have a user select a month range (i.e start month and end month) and then have my charts update based on the selection. In this example it is Jan - Sep of 2021.  I have written another script that performs a query to select a subset of data based on the range selected by the user.  That works, but I need to add/modify the ranges in an existing chart when I run an "update" script.  I have a whole page of charts and I want to be able to programmatically and update each with the updated ranges.

I finally got a script working that modifies the Title and subtitle, but it doesn't update the data series.  Sometimes it does one, sometimes 2 and sometimes none. I don't get it.  The statements look almost identical to what I recorded when I did it manually and recorded a macro, but it doesn't work. This is my first googlescript attempt so the methods, classes, syntax etc. have been a nightmare to navigate.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Row 1 should be the horizontal axis
Row 2 is data
Row 3 is data
Row 4 is data

```
function modify(sheet) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1]; // "access data on the second sheet"
ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
var lastColumn = sheet.getRange('W6').getValue(); //for this example 'W6" contains 'J" because the example goes from column A to Column J

var charts = sheet.getCharts();
var chart = charts[0]; // access the first graph
var ranges = chart.getRanges();
var range = ranges[0]; // access the first range

var rangeA1Notation = "A109:" + lastColumn + "109"; //row 109 column A contains the label "Month Year"
var rangeA1Notation2 = "A110:" + lastColumn + "110";//row 110 column A contains the label "Revenue", Cols B through J have dollar values
var rangeA1Notation3 = "A111:" + lastColumn + "111";//row 110 column A contains the label "Coll Goal", Cols B through J have dollar values
var rangeA1Notation4 = "A112:" + lastColumn + "112";//row 110 column A contains the label "Collected", Cols B through J have dollar values

chart = chart.modify()
.removeRange(range)
.setOption("title", "Collections by Month " + rangeA1Notation)
.setOption("subtitle", "Jan 2021 - Sep 2021" + rangeA1Notation2)
//.addRange(range).setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true).setOption("useFirstColumnAsDomain", true) 
//This did not work
.addRange(sheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation))
.addRange(sheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation2))
.addRange(sheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation3))
.addRange(sheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation4))
.build();

sheet.updateChart(chart)
}
```

Sample Data shown below, the sheet/tab names are on the image:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked Slides advanced service?

Comment: I just looked at it because you suggested it.  I'm not familiar with that service, so it will take some research before I can see whether I could use that or not.  I am hoping someone can just tell me how to modify the ranges on the chart.  If you can do it manually, there has to be a way to do it with a script.

Answer (score 1):

#### You might want to check [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179701683) on Google's Issue Tracker.

It seems that the reason you cannot modify the chart using the `modify` method is due to the fact that this is an ongoing issue on Google's side. I suggest you star the issue as any updates will be posted there.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work.  I abandoned the chart.modify approach and used sheet.removeChart(chart), chart = sheet.newChart() and sheet.insertChart(chart) and it works. I would still like to know if the chart.modify could work or why it didn't.

```
function buildLineChart() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1]; // "access data on the second sheet"

var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
var lastColumn = sheet.getRange('W6').getValue(); //sets the start and end value 
for columns

var rangeA1Notation = "A109:" + lastColumn + "109"; //row 109 column A contains 
the label "Month Year"
var rangeA1Notation2 = "A110:" + lastColumn + "110";//row 110 column A contains 
the label "Revenue" and data
var rangeA1Notation3 = "A111:" + lastColumn + "111";//row 111 column A contains 
the label "Coll Goal" and data
var rangeA1Notation4 = "A112:" + lastColumn + "112";//row 112 column A contains 
the label "Collected" and data


//removes and updates first chart
var charts = sheet.getCharts();
var chart = charts[0];
sheet.removeChart(chart);
chart = sheet.newChart()
.asLineChart()
.addRange(spreadsheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation))
.addRange(spreadsheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation2))
.addRange(spreadsheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation3))
.addRange(spreadsheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation4))
.setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_ROWS)
.setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
.setNumHeaders(-1)
.setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
.setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
.setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', false)
.setOption('subtitle', 'Jan 2021 - Sep 2021')
.setOption('title', 'Collections by Month')
.setOption('annotations.domain.textStyle.color', '#808080')
.setOption('textStyle.color', '#000000')
.setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#1a1a1a')
.setOption('subtitleTextStyle.color', '#999999')
.setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#757575')
.setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.color', '#808080')
.setOption('hAxis.textStyle.color', '#000000')
.setOption('hAxis.titleTextStyle.color', '#000000')
.setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#000000')
.setOption('height', 248)
.setOption('width', 896)
.setPosition(6, 1, 10, 10)
.build();
sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```